# Passing template argument commas through macros safely?

Tags: c++, templates, macros

I'm currently using macros to declare relatively long lists of partially specialized template classes with better brevity.  Somewhat oversimplified examples follow:

```
#define INSTANTIATE_MYTYPE(freeargs, specialization, myvalue) \
template <freeargs> \
struct MyType <specialization> {
  static const bool value = myvalue;
}
```

This works fine if I have no commas to pass in with each case:

```
INSTANTIATE_MYTYPE(typename T, std::vector<T>, true);
```

And it has a tolerable workaround if I have a comma to pass through a single level of macro expansion:

```
#define MacroComma ,
INSTANTIATE_MYTYPE(typename S MacroComma typename T,
                   std::pair<S MacroComma T>, true);
```

But it fails if I try to add an additional layer of macros:

```
#define INSTANTIATE_ALL(freeargs, specialization, myvalue) \
INSTANTIATE_MYTYPE(freeargs, specialization, myvalue); \
INSTANTIATE_ANOTHERTYPE(freeargs, specialization, myvalue); \
INSTANTIATE_ATHIRDTYPE(freeargs, specialization, myvalue)
// etcetera

INSTANTIATE_ALL(typename S MacroComma typename T,
                std::pair<S MacroComma T>, true);
```

Trying to add an extra macro indirection level (via #define MacroComma2 MacroComma or various other attempts) keeps failing.  Extra parentheses don't work when the substitution is going inside a template argument list.  There seems to be a trick with variadic macros which might work, but I'm trying to keep C++2003 standard compliant.  Is it possible to multiply "escape" a comma within a macro in some way in C++2003?

Alternatively, is there a terse way to declare long lists of partial specializations without using macros at all?  My Google-fu hasn't found anything relevant, but it seems like there ought to be some sort of typelist metaprogramming trick.

Comment: Just don't use macros for this. Its not what they are designed for and abusing them just makes it harder for the maintainer. Don't be lazy spell it out.

Comment: maybe smth here:  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html ?

Comment: do you have a long list of templates or template parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one of many solutions using boost pp

```
#define INSTANTIATE_MYTYPE(DATA)                          \
template <BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(0,DATA)>                      \
struct MyType <BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(1,DATA)> {               \
    static const bool value = BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(2,DATA);  \
}

INSTANTIATE_MYTYPE((typename T, ...)
                   (std::vector<T>, ....)
                   (true));
```

further read:  http://www.boostpro.com/mplbook/preprocessor.html